# C++11: Initialize constexpr char array with another constexpr char array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I would like to initialize `constexpr char[]` member with another `constexpr char []` member. Is it possible to do in `C++11` or above?

```js
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
 static constexpr char ValueOne[] = "One";
 static constexpr char ValueTwo[] = "Two";
};

template <typename T>
struct ValueOneHolder {
  static constexpr char Value[] = T::ValueOne; // << How can one initialize this?
};

int main() {
  std::cout << ValueOneHolder<Base>::Value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::array` instead?

Comment: Another option might be a constexpr reference, unless you need unique addresses for the two arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example you may declare Value as the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct ValueOneHolder {
  static constexpr auto Value = T::ValueOne; // << How can one initialize this?
};
```

Please note, GCC will fail to link this example unless you switch to -std=c++17 or add the following lines in a source file.

```
constexpr char Base::ValueOne[];
constexpr char Base::ValueTwo[];
```

With C++14 it is also possible to make a constexpr copy of a constexpr string (or its substring), as shown in example below:

```
template<typename CharT, size_t Size>
struct basic_cestring {
    using value_type = CharT;
    template<size_t... I> constexpr
    basic_cestring(const char* str, index_sequence<I...>)
      : _data{str[I]...} {}
    inline constexpr operator const CharT* () const { return _data; }
    const CharT _data[Size + 1];
};

template<size_t Size>
struct cestring : public basic_cestring<char, Size>  {
    using index = make_index_sequence<Size>;
    constexpr cestring(const char* str)
    : basic_cestring<char, Size>(str, index{}) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to initialize `constexpr char[]` member with another `constexpr char []` member. Is it possible to do in `C++11` or above?

Starting from C++14 you can use `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence`.

If it's OK for you works in a `ValueOneHolder` specialization, you first can develop a `constexpr` function that, given a C-style array, return the size of the array

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t getDim (T const (&)[N])
 { return N; }
```

Nest you can declare `ValueOneHolder` adding a second template parameter with a default value that is an index sequence corresponding to `T::ValueOne`

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<getDim(T::ValueOne)>>
struct ValueOneHolder;
```

and last the easy part: the partial specialization with initialization

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct ValueOneHolder<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { static constexpr char Value[] = { T::ValueOne[Is] ... }; };
```

Don't forget the following line, outside the struct

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr char ValueOneHolder<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>::Value[];
```

The following is a full C++14 compiling example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct Base
 {
   static constexpr char ValueOne[] = "One";
   static constexpr char ValueTwo[] = "Two";
 };

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t getDim (T const (&)[N])
 { return N; }

template <typename T,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<getDim(T::ValueOne)>>
struct ValueOneHolder;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct ValueOneHolder<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { static constexpr char Value[] = { T::ValueOne[Is] ... }; };

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr char ValueOneHolder<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>::Value[];

int main()
 {
   std::cout << ValueOneHolder<Base>::Value << std::endl;
 }
```

If you want a C++11, you can develop a substitute for `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence`.

Comment: I doubt one can make a substitute for index_sequence - it i based on a magic internal feature

Comment: @hutorny - a substitute for `std::index_sequence` is trivial; it's a substitute for `std::make_index_sequence` (or better: for `std::make_integer_sequence`) that is more complicated; but not so much. The real problem is that `std::make_integer_sequence` should (the standard say) be a `std::integer_sequence`, not only something that inherit from it. And this I don't know how to make in C++11 (but this problem require only a little change in `ValueOneHolder`s code)